# Call virtual functions from a reference

Tags: c++, reference

I have a structure like this

```
struct structure
{
    BaseObject &A; //BaseObject has a function declared as virtual
};
```

In run time, I am dynamically assign an object to &A

```
structure *s = new structure;
DerivedObjectB *B = new DerivedObjectB(); //Derived class overloads the virtual function 
s->A = *B; //s is a pointer of the structure. S has been initialized
```

I can compile this code but I am getting a seg-fault error in runtime. 
I have a restriction that I can not use a pointer. 
This is not a homework. The compiler I am using as a reverse compiler has a restriction of using pointers because of an issue in building SSA

Comment: That code cant compile, references are not assignable. Show us real code.

Comment: @K-ballo I disagree (about the compile part).

Comment: "*I have a restriction that I can not use a pointer.*" Who would give you such a silly restriction? Is this homework?

Comment: We need more information. Where does `s` come from?

Comment: @Luchian Grigore: True, it will compile but not do what the OP expects.

Comment: This is not a homework. The compiler I am using as a reverse compiler has a restriction of using pointers because of an issue in building SSA

Comment: And `s` is a valid pointer that points to a struct with valid reference to a live object? :-)

Comment: Might be relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-the-slicing-problem-in-c

Comment: The code is ill-formed because `structure` has no default constructor; the reference type data member inhibits the implicit declaration of a default constructor (in C++11, its implicitly declared default constructor is defined as deleted).

Comment: @James : If I'm not mistaken, `structure` is an aggregate type, so the following should work as-is: `BaseObject a; structure s = { a };`.

Comment: @ildjarn:  Yes, aggregate initialization would work.  `new structure` won't, though, because of the missing default constructor.

Comment: @James : Ah, I see what you mean. Somehow I thought you were referring to the definition of `structure` itself as ill-formed. Sorry for the noise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you cannot use a pointer, you must use a reference. 
If you use a reference, it *must be initialized to it's final value as it's constructed*.

```
struct structure
{
    BaseObject &A; //BaseObject has a function declared as virtual
    structure(BaseObject &A_) : A(A_) {}
};

DerivedObjectB *B = new DerivedObjectB(); 
structure *s = new structure(*B); //done
//keep in mind you cannot delete `B` until _after_ you delete `s`
```

Your code above shouldn't have compiled since a `structure` could not be created that way since it had no automatic default structure since it has a reference member.  Also, Even if it did compile, the `A` member would have been a `BaseObject` *copy* of the `DerivedObjectB`'s parent `BaseObject` object, or some other bizzare not-what-you-wanted.

Are you *absolutely sure* you cannot use pointers there?  That makes no sense at all, and makes this very difficult to work with.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change object referenced by A, once `structure` is constructed.
What you probably would like to have is:

```
struct structure
{
  structure() : A(NULL) {}
  ~structure() { if (this->A) { delete this->A; } }
  BaseObject * A;
};

structure *s = new structure;
s->A = new DerivedObjectB();
```

Anyway, using raw pointers is error prone and you should consider it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm betting you just declared

```
structure* s;
```

or

```
structure* s = NULL;
```

amirite? <del>Otherwise, there's no reason for the crash.</del>

**Or** `s->A` references an object that went out of scope, so when you call `operator =` on it you get into undefined behavior.

It's one of these two.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Since I initialized the structure I guess its the second case.

Answer (score 0):

This should not even compile. The reference cannot be rebound after construction, and you should have received an error telling you that it must have been bound to something.

Comment: It's not even bound at construction.

Comment: @Greg Either that is a bug or a GNU extension (I hope it's not the latter). Try with a more recent compiler and without crazy extensions.

Comment: I'm as surprised as you are. Explanation: http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=39045